# Imparfait or Passé Composé: “j'étais absent” or “j'ai été absent”?

Tags: passé-composé, imparfait

I am a beginner in French language and I still find it hard to wrap around my head between *Imparfait* and *Passé Composé*. I know that *Imparfait* is used to describe continuous actions in past as well as description of a situation and habit in the past.

So, if I have to say "I was absent because I was sick." then which form should I choose: *Imparfait* (J'étais absent parce que j'étais malade) or *Passé Composé* (J'ai été absent parce que j'ai été malade)? I know *Imparfait* is the correct choice here but I don't know why? Why can't we use *Passé Composé* here? Should I consider it as a description of a situation? A proper explanation will help. Can anyone also give an example of a sentence using *j'ai été*?

Comment: I expect both could be used according to context, even *J'ai été absent parce que j'étais malade*. Would the answers to the following question be of any help before you get an answer to yours. [Passe Compose vs Imparfait - Inconsistency in Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22597/358), [Imparfait or Passé Composé?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25117/358),

Comment: [Comment utiliser le passé composé et l'imparfait en présence d'une indication de temps supplémentaire ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8901/358). They don't really answer your question because the agreement of tenses could also be a point in your question.

Answer (score 12):

There are a lot of questions on this, so I'm not sure if my adding yet another answer is of much value, but I figure if there are a bunch that haven't been marked duplicates, there's room for another take. :)

Here's how I often describe these two tenses to my students, in case any of these comparisons help. (P.S. None of them are absolute, just generalizations!)

---

**Basics**

The *passé composé* is used to talk about a particular moment. You could ask what time or what day it happened — there's some individual unit, be it a a second, an hour, or a day, that corresponds to the action, like a doctor writing time of birth or death in her notebook.

The *imparfait* is used to talk about a span of time. You could ask when it started and stopped. It could be something you were in the middle of doing, something you used to do regularly, or a way you felt over the course of a day.

---

**Did or was doing?**

The *passé composé* is often translated "-ed".

> J'ai marché, tu as parlé, et on a mangé de la crème glacée.
>   
> *I walked, you talked, and we ate ice cream.*

The *imparfait* is often translated "was... -ing".

> Je marchais, tu parlais, et on mangeait de la crème glacée.
>   
> *I was walking, you were talking, and we were eating ice cream.*

One exception is that English often uses a simple past for emotional states even though French prefers the *imparfait* :

> Il se sentait un peu triste.
>   
> *He felt a little sad. (Or: He was feeling a little sad.)*

And especially for the verbs *avoir* and *être* :

> Elle avait trois frères.
>   
> *She had three brothers.*
>
> Nous étions en détresse.
>   
> *We were in distress.*

More on this below with your "be absent" example. :)

---

**Move on or dwell on?**

The *passé composé* is when you want to mention the action and move on.

> We ate ice cream that day, remember? You got a brain freeze and said you'd never eat ice cream again.
>   
> *On a mangé de la crème glacée ce jour-là, tu t'en souviens ? Tu as eu le cerveau gelé et tu as dit que tu ne mangerais plus jamais de crème glacée.*

The *imparfait* is when you want to dwell in the action and say what happened in the middle of it.

> You were eating your ice cream when we suddenly heard a shout.
>   
> *Tu mangeais ta crème glacée quand on a soudain entendu un cri.*

Similarly, "while" *pendant que* is a great clue that the *imparfait* is appropriate. Then the other half of the sentence, the thing that happens during the action, is in *passé composé*.

> While you were showering, your mother called.
>   
> *Pendant que tu te douchais, ta mère a appelé/téléphoné.*

---

**Finished or not?**

The *passé composé* is for something that got finished.

> They fixed the roof.
>   
> *Ils ont réparé le toit.*

The *imparfait* is for something that got interrupted.

> They were fixing the roof, but it started to rain.
>   
> *Ils réparaient le toit, mais il a commencé à pleuvoir.*

This sense is also very similar to *être en train de* :

> They were fixing the roof, but it started to rain.
>   
> *Ils étaient en train de réparer le toit, mais il a commencé à pleuvoir.*

---

**Became or continued to be?**

> Charles I took the throne of England in 1625. He was in power until his execution in 1649.
>   
> *Charles I est monté sur le trône anglais en 1625. Il était au pouvoir jusqu'à son exécution en 1649.*

---

**"I was absent"**

The subtle cases are when the verb describes a state: "be absent" or any other adjective. Something that's naturally a period of time no matter how you frame it. Then they become nearly interchangeable.

Do you want to say you were absent; the fact is established; you don't need to dwell on particular events during the absence?

> I was absent for two days back in March. I was sick.
>   
> *J'ai été absent deux jours là, en mars. J'ai été/J'étais malade.*

- You could replace "I was absent for two days" with "I missed two days" *j'ai manqué deux jours* and have the exact same meaning and perspective on the fact.

Or do you want to say that you were absent, and pause there for a second because something else happened at the same time?

> Yes, you did give the instructions for the homework, but I was absent and missed them.
>   
> *Oui, vous avez bien donné les consignes pour le devoir, mais j'étais absent et je les ai manquées.*

- You could replace "I was absent" with "I wasn't there" *je n'étais pas là* and have the exact same meaning and perspective on the fact.

But I don't think anyone would find it too strange if you used the other tense in either case.

---

**Appendix: Still true in the present or not?**

It's worth taking up @Maxence1402's useful answer, although I don't cover this when first introducing the *imparfait*.

Both the *imparfait* and the *passé composé* are past tenses, but the latter is technically called "present perfect". It can still have an effect on the present, because of how *avoir* is conjugated.

Here's the usual way to translate a *passé composé* verb:

> J'ai enseigné toute ma vie.
>   
> *I taught all my life.*

But it could also have this next meaning, which new students tend to use more than they should because it makes so much sense when going one word at a time:

> J'ai enseigné toute ma vie.
>   
> *I've taught all my life.*

In the first translation, the speaker no longer teaches. But in the second one, they still teach!

The relevance for your question is that you could say *J'ai été absent* and depending on the context, it could still be true now. You might not have returned yet. But if you say *J'étais absent*, you're definitely back by now.

This might be confusing because it sounds like the opposite of the "Finished or not?" point from earlier. I would say this is a separate meaning of the *passé composé*.

Comment: Nice insightful answer, but a few comments regarding the examples featuring Barack Obama. The first would actually require a _forme surcomposée_: ‘Barack Obama **a été élu** président deux fois’. The second one would preferably be written with _passé simple_, which has nothing to do with the question here, but since this tense is pretty much non-existent is spoken French, the _passé composé_ would most often be used: ‘Il a été président pendant huit ans’. For _imparfait_, something like: ‘He was president when an Ebola outbreak occured in the US’ would work better.

Comment: It would also be nice to have the French version of your examples. Hope this is not too much asking... :)

Comment: @Feelew Merci. Révision à venir !

Comment: Thank you for explaining in details. Could you please give some examples in French alongside the English ones?

Comment: Added those examples. @Feelew or any other native speaker, feel free to touch up or comment on any that aren't quite right!

Comment: Just a few modifications: I added _téléphoné_ as a possible translation of _called_, as one or the other are used, but _téléphoné_ adds a perspective on various translation possibilities that may not come naturally to English native speakers. Also, _tu ne mangerais plus jamais de crème glacée_ sounds better than **de la crème glacée**.

Comment: @Feelew Good catch! Merci...

Comment: the imparfait can actually be translated as a simple past in English and often is. Sorry to be a naysayer. I can't think of a specific example here but often come across this when translating.

Comment: @Lambie Definitely agreed. For example, with emotional states: "Il se sentait ..." - "He felt..." I hoped that would pass with the "generalization" disclaimer but I'll edit to make a remark there.

Comment: @Luke Sawczak Ah right, that's a great example. Sorry to be a nitpicker.

Comment: @Lambie Pas de problème, j'aime recevoir tes suggestions !

Comment: «Elle avait trois frères» is a great example. It might be interesting to note that «Elle a eu trois frères» would imply that she doesn't have all 3 of them anymore (either one or more of them died or disappeared totally from her life, as a result of a feud or emigration to a faraway land, or we are actually talking about people from the past, now deceased).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Luke Sawczak's beautiful answer, there are some special meanings of some verbs which might help.

---

**SAVOIR**

Il **savait** l'adresse = *He **knew** the address*

Il **a su** l'adresse = *He **found out** the address*

---

**CONNAÎTRE**

Tu **connaissais** mon voisin? = ***Did** you **know** my neighbour?*

Tu **as connu** mon voisin? = ***Did** you **meet** my neighbour?*

---

**POUVOIR**

Il **ne pouvait pas** sortir = *He **couldn't** go out (it was hard for him)*

Il **n'a pas pu** sortir = *He **couldn't** (and didn't) go out*

---

**VOULOIR**

Je **voulais** partir = *I **wanted** to leave*

J'ai **voulu** partir = *I **tried** to leave*

Je **ne voulais pas** partir = *I **didn't want** to leave*

Je **n'ai pas voulu** partir = *I **refused** to leave*

---

**AVOIR**

Elle **avait** faim = *She **was** hungry*

Elle **a eu** faim = *She **got hungry***

Comment: Great examples!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think my comment is as valuable as an answer but here it is. As a French native, I would rather use the imparfait "j'étais absent" since this event is over.

However, you could also say "j'ai été absent de trop nombreuses fois" *I was absent too many times*, because this event has consequences on the present.

The problem between imparfait and passé composé is IMO as hard as dealing with present perfect and preterit for a non-English native.

I hope this helped you, have a good day.